# Making a phonebook in Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to make a phone_book in shell (bash)..

Here's what the program should do.

1. Add a number : You ask for the name and the number.If it doesn't exist already ( verification) then add a file in the same directory called $name and contain 1 line: the number.
2. Obtain the liste of names already saved.
3. Look for a number by giving his name ( we have to verify also if it exists or not.
4. modify a number ( verification also)
5. looking for a name by giving his number.( verification).

I Think that we have to use case I looked in the net, but I have difficulties with Shell.
Hope you helps me guys. Don't hesitate to ask me questions. Thanks

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " 1)Ajouter une fiche
 2)Obtenir la liste des noms déjà enregistrés
 3)Chercher un numéro de téléphone
 4)Modifier un numero de téléphone
 5)Rechercher un nom"
read x
case $x in 
    1)
    echo " Tapez le nom à rajouter"
    read nom
    touch $nom
    ;;
```

UPDATE:
I have almost finished it, I have a problem with the 5) when i type an existant number , it always telling me that it doesn't exist..

Feel free to make some improvement in my code :)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " 1)Ajouter une fiche
2)Obtenir la liste des noms déjà enregistrés
3)Chercher un numéro de téléphone 
4)Modifier un numero de téléphone 
5)Rechercher un nom"
read x
case $x in 
1)
echo " Tapez le nom à rajouter"
read nom
while [ -f $nom ]; do

    echo "Le fichier existe déjà"
    echo " Tapez le nom à rajouter"
    read nom
done


    touch $nom
    echo " Maintenant, tapez le numero de la personne à rajouter"
    read numero
    echo $numero >> $nom
;;
2)
echo $(ls);;
3)
echo " Tapez le nom de la personne que vous recherchez"
read nomrech
while [ ! -f $nomrech ]; do
echo "Le fichier n'existe pas"
read nomrech
done
cat $nomrech
;;
4)
echo "Tapez le nom d'un contacte à modifier"
read nommodif
while [ ! -f $nommodif ]; do
echo "Le fichier n'existe pas"
read nommodif
done
echo "Tapez le nouveau numéro à modifier"
read nouvnum
echo $nouvnum > $nommodif
;;
5)
echo " Tapez le numero de la personne que vous cherchez"
read numchercher
while   ! grep -i "$numchercher" *  ; do
echo "ce numero n'existe pas "
read nomchercher
done
grep $numchercher *
;;
esac
```

Comment: http://www.lions-wing.net/lessons/database/address.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to think about how you will actually store the datas. Then, try to associate an action to each items:

1. Create a file named by the input containing one single line
2. browse the folder and extract all the filenames in that directory
3. find a file in a directory, given its name
4. modify the content of a file given its name (you can trash the content of the file at that point)
5. Find a filename given a pattern

So basically, I think you can manage to do the assignment with the following commands: `cat`, `find`, `*`, `grep` and that's it!

**Update:**

For your last question (5th point), it seems to me that your code is really complicated. Have a look on this sample:

```
$ echo 0123456789 > john                                                                                       
$ echo 0987654321 > bob                                                                                        
$ grep 0987654321 *                                                                                            
bob:0987654321
$ grep jfkljlfds *                                                                                             
$ echo $?                                                                                                      
1
$ grep 0123456789 *                                                                                            
john:0123456789
$ echo $?                                                                                                      
0
$  false                                                                                                        
$ echo $?                                                                                                      
1
$ false || echo "oops that one didn't work"                                                                    
oops that one didn't work
```

Now I think you have everything you need to keep going.

`$?` is the return code from previous command. If you have a look on `man grep (1)`:

> EXIT STATUS
>          The exit status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not found.  If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX error handling
>          code should check for '2' or greater.)

So basically, the trick using the `or` operator (`||`) is used to display an error only if the left part returned false.

I suppose `read name; grep $name * || echo "$name was not found"` would do the trick.

And by the way, you're often asking arguments twice (after checking). You shouldn't need that. The variable still exists after your test.

Comment: good advice. @user3568611 : make your best attempt to add those commands as appropriate, and if you are still stuck feel free to post a new question. Best to show some sample inputs, expected output, your code, your current output and any error messages (exact copy/paste). Good luck to all.

Comment: OK I have almost done the first, but without verifying, how can I do to check firstly that the file doesn't exist ?

Comment: `file="/path/to/file_to_process.txt" ; if [[ ! -f "$file" ]] ; then echo "no file:$file" ; exit 1; fi` Is a place to start. Good luck.

Comment: I have posted my code , could you please check it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update, it seems so hard to me too.. what does mean contact ➤, and when you do echo $ , the $ contain the result of grep ?, can you explain more or.. give me the answer because I don't have so much time to think about it.. the deadline is very soon..

Comment: @user3568611: contact ➤ is my prompt, when in the folder named contact. I did update my answer, you now have a solution I guess :(